# run chrome extension on page load

Tags: javascript

i have found this extension `Behind The Overlay` which removes the overlay on
the webpage that we visit.
for doing so we have to click on the extension icon.

i want to do this programmatically.
i.e on page load the extension should run automatically

https://github.com/NicolaeNMV/BehindTheOverlay

i want to add delay before this line

```
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "overlay_remover.js"});
```

how to do this?

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.active) {

    // add some delay here


    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "overlay_remover.js"});
  }
})
```

Comment: background.js does not send alerts. Instead, try using `console.log()` and [check the extension's console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/10210841) (**It will not show in the website's console!!! Extensions have their own console!**)

Comment: @Rojo i have updated the question please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by editing your background.js replacing `alert()` with `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "/js/overlay_remover.js"});` and include the [overlay remover](https://github.com/NicolaeNMV/BehindTheOverlay/blob/master/chrome/js/overlay_remover.js) in your files:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.active) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "overlay_remover.js"});
    }, 3000); // 3000 = delay in milliseconds (3 seconds)
  }
})
```

Note that you should keep your manifest the same and keep your background.js

Comment: this worked, but i just found that the webpage that i want to remove overlay from , loads some data even after page loading is complete, so i want to run this script after some delay, how can i do this?

Comment: i want to add some delay before this line executes  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "overlay_remover.js"});

Comment: @user4599 How long do you want the delay (in ms)? 1000 ms = 1 second

Comment: i want to see how much delay will work , by doing trial and error

Comment: 3 second possibly

Comment: @user4599 I have implemented `setTimeout` with a delay of 3000 milliseconds. Note that users will have different loading times depending on wifi speed, server latency, CPU, and RAM speed.